# Multi-index Searching in ElasticSearch (Tire)

Tags: json, full-text-search, elasticsearch

Large web applications offer a "global" search which combines data from various fulltext indices (this would be a table in SQL) to provide a combined search result ordered by its score. So lets say you have videos, blog articles and users, then when you type in "home" into the search it could yield results like this (ordered by score):

- My Home (Blog Article)
- Home Town (User)
- I want to go home (video)

Does anyone know how to perform such a combined search using ElasticSearch? Preferably using the Tire gem for Rails, but raw ElasticSearch JSON data would also work.

Thanks.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

regarding *Tire*, there's an important distinction: are you using it standalone or in the ActiveRecord/ActiveModel integration.

In the former case, just search against multiple indices, `Tire.search ['indexA', 'indexB'] do ... end`. Or search against the whole cluster, `Tire.search do ... end` (equivalent to `curl 'http://localhost:9200/_search?q=*'`).

In the latter case, *Tire* does not handle multi-model searches well, at the moment. Notice this pull request: https://github.com/karmi/tire/pull/218 -- build your gem with this patch applied and help test out the solution.

**UPDATE**

Current *Tire* (> 0.4) can load multiple model instances just fine. See the [integration test](https://github.com/karmi/tire/blob/d5c08fbc0fd8322f5ff1db1585c94a886126b9ed/test/integration/active_record_searchable_test.rb#L355-412) for example.

Comment: A reply directly from the owner of the gem :) Many thanks!

And Yes I am using it with ActiveRecord. In the worst case event I will just set the :load => false so that it won't spawn any ActiveRecord Objects.

Comment: Yes, without `:load`, you'll get back "elastic" models, `Tire::Results::Item` instances. However, multi-model searches is something we should support and I like the patch in issue #218.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure that the http://127.0.0.1:9200/_search endpoint will do the trick for you. Over 99% of my data is in one index, so its hard for me to verify this for you here.

Also, check out the multi-search endpoint: http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/multi-search.html

Comment: What's the benefit/drawback from putting most of your data into a single ES index? Searching is definitely easier, less complex, but any downsides?

Comment: Sometimes it's unfeasible to have just 1 single index. Sometimes you just miscalculate # of shards upfront, and creating a new index is faster than reindexing everything again into another index.